Why things like baby step/giant step don’t work when trying to find the preimage of hash?
Even with elliptic curves, when I know the private key is in a specific key range, I can use baby step giant step in addition to Pollard Kangaroo.
Now if I’m given a sha512 hash, and that I know it’s preimage is a 64 bits integer, why baby step/giant step not usefull to search the preimage generating the given hash within such continuous 64 bits range ?

Well, baby step/giant step works because elliptic curves allows the search to be rewritten as:
$$F(a) = C - H(b)$$
(where $a$ is the upper bits of the key, $F(a) = [2^{32} \cdot a]G$, $b$ is the lower bits, $H(b) = [b]G$, and $C$ is the public key)
By rewriting it this way, we can generate a list of $F(a)$ values, a list of $C - H(b)$ values, and look for a match.
This doesn't work for hash preimages because we don't have a way to rewrite hashes in this form.
